# How to establish trust between IIS and SQL Server on different machines?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a .net web app hosting in IIS6 with Windows Authentication and anonymous access disabled. The web app is making connection to a SQL Server that is in the same domain, but on a different machine.

I want to have the IIS Worker process acount I_USR_... to be granted access to the SQL Server.

Will this work ?

(Is there a one to one trust ? Or should I make some extra effort to make the trust work ?)

(edit)
On this [page](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-my-connection-string-look-like.html) I read:

IUSR_ must be in the domain, and given proper access to the SQL Server; or, you must disable anonymous access on the site / application - which will allow IIS to pass the users' credentials to SQL Server. Not doing either of these things will result in an error.

Comment: Are you getting a particular error message?

Comment: Not tested yet. The app is currently on one server (web app + SQL Server). The app will be moved to a new data centre where we want to split the web and database part in 2 servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work if you provide SQL access to the identity of the application pool.

There is no way you can pass your users' credentials to the SQL even with impersonation.

Comment: That is it in fact. I made an app pool and create a service account with least privileges on AD. The service account is member of the I_WPG group and that account has login access to the SQL instance. For the SQL DB I granted SP rights on that account and CRUD on tables by SQL roles and that all works fine!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you are using windows authentication and SQL server is on the same box then you do not need to do the above if you use impersonation and user has access to the database. But 99 out of 100, sql is on another box.

Comment: How do you "provide SQL access to the identity of the application pool?" Without having to create a new AD user.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine either by allowing that domain account access on the SQL Server box or creating a SQL Server account and use that to query the database.

More information on Connection Strings and Trusted Connections here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: virtual -1. Giving the user access will not work, I have already investigated it before. Even with impersonation it does not work.

Comment: You wouldn't give IUSR_ SQL Server access, that's only for access to the web site. The connection to sql should be another account or the identity the app pool is running as.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to set up a sql user account or a domain account specific for you connection.
Having the same account helps with connection pooling:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you must configure Active Directory to establish trust between your web server and the database server.   This is called delegation.   It is something you must actively configure for each server, because it is inherently unsafe to allow a process to take someone's credentials and use it all over the network.

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx

A slightly more readable version:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3696506/Setting-Up-Delegation-for-Linked-Servers.htm